# Ngrx effects: Can't get entities from the store or service

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm developing an angular 8 app using ngrx (store, effects, entities, storedevtools). I'm also discovering ngrx.
I followed tutorials from the official doc and everything was ok until I decided to optimize the http requests of my app.

I want to have an effect checking into the store if the entities are already loaded and if not contact my service.

I googled and found this example then inspired of it, but I have an issue
https://medium.com/@haldun7/caching-http-requests-while-using-ngrx-effects-98abd50c5c78

My issue from the console browser is :

> ERROR TypeError: "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."

This is the effect where the issue appears :

```
  @Effect() 
  loadAllCountries$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.CountryActionTypes.LOAD_ALL_COUNTRIES),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromReducers.selectAllCountries))),
    switchMap((list) => { // <= this guy is a [never, Country[]] object and I don't know why :(
      if (list[1].length !== 0) {

        var temp = list[1];

        return [new fromActions.LoadCountriesSuccess( {countries: temp })];
      }
      this.service.getCountries().pipe(
        map(data => new fromActions.LoadCountriesSuccess({ countries: data })))
    })
  );
```

That's a quite strange because when debugging step by step, list[1] equals 0 so the else part should be executed without problems.

This is the non-optimized version of the Effect which is working perfectly

```
  @Effect() 
  loadAllCountries$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.CountryActionTypes.LOAD_ALL_COUNTRIES),
    switchMap(() => 
         this.service.getCountries().pipe(
         map(data => new fromActions.LoadCountriesSuccess({ countries: data })) 
      )));
```

Basically I have 2 questions:

1. Does anyone know what is my code error ?
2. Do you know why the withLatestFrom returns a [never, Country[]], I think an observable should be more helpful.

I can provide other code part (reducers, actions...) if needed, but it is very close to this example I also used to learn ngrx : https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/ngrx/ngrx-entity-example

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed return here

```
return this.service.getCountries().pipe(
        map(data => new fromActions.LoadCountriesSuccess({ countries: data }))).
```

Therefore your switchMap doesn't return anything.
In that case

```
switchMap(() => 
         this.service.getCountries().pipe(
         map(data => new fromActions.LoadCountriesSuccess({ countries: data })) 
      )))
```

Your code returns result of `this.service.getCountries()..` automatically, since it's one-line arrow function.

Comment: Vitalii, you are totally right. I spent too many time on this code to see the return was missing :)
Do you know there is any way to display some warnings with VS Code? I'm surprised that the TS allows me to forget a key word.

Comment: Not sure about VS Code. Try WebStorm trial, see if that's something that will work better for you :)